# how to do SSH with -t option using paramiko

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to login to some remote servers and trying to fetch the system info. During that process I have faced an issued in some of the servers, where the password is not really required to execute commands as `sudo`. To overcome this issue and make the script generic came up with option like this `sudo -k udisksctl status`, i.e providing `-k` option so that everytime it requests for a password.

Now a different problem has occured : When trying to login to some of the servers the following error is occuring: `sorry you must have a tty to run sudo centos`. When googled out came to know about the option of doing ssh with `-t` option from [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-sudo-sorry-you-must-haveattytorun/)

**So my Question is how to do SSH with `-t` option using paramiko ? Or How to overcome this problem ?**

```
import paramiko
import pprint

ip_list = [
["192.168.11.44", "root", "aaa", "aaa"],
["192.168.11.6", "root", "bbb", "bbb"]
]
os_check_list = ["DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION"]
os = None

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

for ip in ip_list:
    ssh.connect(ip[0], username = ip[1], password = ip[2])

    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("sudo -k udisksctl status")
    stdin.write(ip[3]+"\n")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `get_pty` parameter:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("sudo -k udisksctl status", get_pty=True)
```

There's some side effect though. With `get_pty=True`, all output will be sent to `stdout` and so you cannot get data from `stderr` any more.

Comment: can you please add some more info about what the **get_pty** is doing in this particular command..

Comment: just like `ssh -t`, it asks the remote ssh server to allocate a pty (pseudo terminal).